# Include template form to django admin

Tags: python, django, forms, django-templates

Is it possible to include model form template in django admin as follows?

**models.py**

```
class Customer(models.Model):
     name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
     designation = models.CharField(max_length=20)
     gender = models.BooleanField()
```

**forms.py**

```
class CustomerForm(forms.ModelForm)
    gender = forms.TypedChoiceField(
            choices=GENDER_CHOICES, widget=forms.RadioSelect(renderer=HorizontalRadioRenderer), coerce=int, )
    class Meta:
        model = Customer
```

**template.html**

```
<form action="{% url 'verinc.views.customerView' %}" method="POST">{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }} 
    <input id="submit" type="button" value="Click" /></form>
```

**views.py**

```
def customerView(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = CustomerForm(request.POST)
    else:
        form = CustomerForm()
return render_to_response('myapp/template.html', {'form' : form,})
```

**admin.py**

```
class CustomerInline(admin.StackedInline)
    model= Customer
    form = CustomerForm
    template = 'myapp/template.html
```

When I view the form in `url (localhost/myapp/customer)` it displays all the fields correctly. But when I view it in admin page it displays only the submit button in the block. My requirement is to view the form using templates in admin page, so that i could use some AJAX script for further process. Any help is most appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well , Its not possible . But you can implement like this :

You should create file called `admin_views.py` in your app `customer`.

Then add url in your urls.py like

```
(r'^admin/customer/customerView/$', 'myapp.customer.admin_views.customerView'),
```

Write your view implementation inside admin_views.py like :

```
from myapp.customer.models import Customer
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response
from django.contrib.admin.views.decorators import staff_member_required


def customerView(request):
    return render_to_response(
        "admin/customer/template.html",
        {'custom_context' : {}},
        RequestContext(request, {}),
    )
customerView = staff_member_required(customerView)
```

And inside your admin template extend `base_site.html` like this one :

```
{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}

{% block title %}Custmer admin view{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<div id="content-main">
     your content from context or static / dynamic...
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Thats it . hit that new url after admin login . Note **Not Tested** :) .

Comment: Yeah, well this works fine in other url. My requirement is i have other models in admin page where I need to embed the above in Add page.